# SELECT row from Table twice in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

Related Question which didn't solve my problem :
[Selecting a column from a table in MySQL twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017402/selecting-a-column-from-a-table-in-mysql-twice)

I'm currently trying to create a comment area for my site where user can add comments and reply to other users comments.

So whenever I save a comment to the database, I add this data :

- Text        : User entered Text
- Question ID : An ID referring to a sub-site on my Website
- User ID     : The user ID of the User sending the comment
- reply ID    : ID of the comment this comment is replying to

The tables and the result (should) look like this

[image: Tables and join result]

Now when trying to get all the comments for a specific site including the name of the user who wrote the comment that is referred to in the reply_to column, i hit a wall.

What I have done so far:

```
SELECT comment.id,
       comment.reply_to,
       comment.text,
       comment.date,
       comment.user_id,
       users.name,
       users.user_group,
       user_group.name AS group_name,
       users_to.name AS reply_to_username,
FROM COMMENT,
     users,
     user_group
JOIN COMMENT AS comment_to ON COMMENT.reply_to = comment_to.id
JOIN users AS users_to ON comment_to.user_id = users.id
WHERE COMMENT.question_id = 1
  AND COMMENT.user_id = users.id
  AND users.user_group = user_group.id
  AND COMMENT.id <> 0
ORDER BY COMMENT.date DESC
```

The problem I'm running into there is, it always tells me that comment.reply_to is an unknown column.

Can I even join the same table I am currently selecting with that SELECT statement. 
I know I could do this with 2 separate statements, but I'd rather do it this way because of performance reasons.

Comment: don't mix join styles. `from x,y,z join` is horribly hacky. pick one style and stick with it.

Comment: There's no php here to support the question and you have a syntax error. checking for errors would have told you about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.reply_to,
a.text,
a.date,
a.user_id,
b.name,      
b.user_group,
c.name as group_name,
users_to.name   as reply_to_username
FROM comment a
INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id
INNER JOIN user_group c ON b.user_group = c.id
INNER JOIN comment as comment_to ON a.reply_to = comment_to.id
INNER JOIN users   as users_to ON comment_to.user_id = users_to.id
WHERE a.question_id = 1
AND a.id  <> 0
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

That solved my problem. Now everything is returned as expected.
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?  There was extra comma and comment_positive is undefined.

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.reply_to,
a.text,
a.date,
a.user_id,
b.name,      
b.user_group,
c.name as group_name,
users_to.name   as reply_to_username
FROM comment a
INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id = b.id
INNER JOIN user_group c ON b.user_group = c.id
INNER JOIN comment as comment_to ON a.reply_to = comment_to.id
INNER JOIN users   as users_to ON comment_to.user_id = users.id
WHERE a.question_id = 1
AND a.id  <> 0
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

Comment: *"comment_positive is undefined"* - huh?

Comment: had to change INNER JOIN users   as users_to ON comment_to.user_id = users.id to INNER JOIN users   as users_to ON comment_to.user_id = users_to.id but other than that, it worked! Thank you, didn't expect an answer so quickly.